# HTML Canvas Rotating a character's gun to face mouse

Tags: html, canvas

I'm very new to Javascript and I've started a simple game. I want the character's gun to rotate to follow the mouse. So far, movement and everything else works fine, except that when I added the rotation functionality  the character seems to rotate in a huge circle around the screen. Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jvwr8bug/#

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.top;
  var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.left;
  return {
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY
  };
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var m = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    mouse.x = m.x;
    mouse.y = m.y;
  }, false);
}, false);
```

The error seems to be somewhere there but obviously it could be something else

**Edit: Thanks to Blindman67 for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were rotating the current transform by `rotation` each frame. `ctx.rotate(a)` rotates the current transform so each time it is called you increase the rotation amount by `a`. Think of it as a relative rotation rather than setting the absolute rotation.

To fix your code replace the canon rendering with

```
  //cannon
  //ctx.rotate(rotation);  // << you had

  // setTransform overwrites the current transform with a new one
  // The arguments represent the vectors for the X and Y axis
  // And are simply the direction and length of one pixel for each axis
  // And a coordinate for the origin.
  // All values are in screen/canvas pixels coordinates
  // setTransform(xAxisX, xAxisY, yAxisX, yAxisY, originX, originY)
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y); // set center of rotation (origin) to center of gun
  ctx.rotate(rotation); // rotate about that point.
  ctx.fillStyle = "#989898";
  ctx.fillRect(15, - 12.5, 25, 25);  // draw relative to origin
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#4f4f4f";
  ctx.strokeRect( 15,- 12.5, 25, 25); // draw relative to origin
  //body
  ctx.fillStyle = "#5079c4";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, size, 0, Math.PI * 2); // draw relative to origin
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  // can't leave the transformed state as is because that will effect anything else
 // that will be rendered. So reset to the default.
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);   // restore the origin to the default
```

And a few more problems to get it working

Just above rendering the canon get the direction to the mouse

```
// you had coordinates mixed up
// rotation = Math.atan2(mouse.x - y, mouse.y - x); // you had (similar)

rotation = Math.atan2(mouse.y - y, mouse.x - x);
```

And your mouse event listener is mixing up coordinates and not running very efficiently

Replace all your mouse code with. You don't need onload as the canvas already exists.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = evt.clientX - rect.left; // you had evt.clientX - rect.top
    mouse.y = evt.clientY - rect.top;  // you had evt.clientY - rect.left
}, false);
```